# Understanding the for loop iterator in Python

Tags: python, loops, iterator

Hello I am trying to make sure that I am understanding the for loop correctly in python.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print i
```

I understand the range(1,10) will return a list that is iterable, and the for loop will call that lists **iter**() function which will return an iterator. But my question is specifically with the 'i'. Is the iterator being returned from the list range(1,10) produces by the for loop calling its **iter**() function, being stored in 'i' and the loop will ultimately run the next() function on i to iterate through the list?

Comment: No, i is the value from each iteration.

Comment: i inherits whatever is in the current index. so if you would have [1, "foo", 3.4]. then the index 0 is an actual int, index 1 is an actual string and index 2 is an actual float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

is equivalent to

```
_iterator = iter(range(1, 10))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(_iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(i)
```

That is, in the beginning of each iteration, the next value that the iterator yields is assigned to the loop variable (or variables).

Comment: That `try/except` should really be around the `next`

Comment: @Eric is correct, as you can `raise StopIteration` during a for loop and get the exception, whereas your answer would suggest it would be suppressed.

Comment: @Eric true dat, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From [Understanding Python's "for" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-for-statement.htm):

> And in its simplest and original form, this is exactly what the for-in statement does; when you write

```
for name in train:
    do something with name
```

> the interpreter will simply fetch `train[0]`and assign it to `name`, and then execute the code block. It’ll then
>   fetch `train[1]`, `train[2]`, and so on, until it gets an `IndexError`.

---

Alternatively, we can use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#module-dis) and examine the machine code:

```
>>> def forloop():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print i
>>> dis.dis(forloop)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 31)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER            
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                11 (to 30)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             25 PRINT_ITEM          
             26 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             27 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   30 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

We setup a loop, call range, and then:

`16`[`FOR_ITER`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-FOR_ITER)`11 (to 30)`

which pushes the *result* of the iterator onto the stack, which we then `STORE_FAST` as `i` and subsequently use.

when the iterator completes, `FOR_ITER` "`TOS` is popped [the iterator], and the bytecode counter is incremented by delta." which `dis` shows takes us to 30: `POP_BLOCK` which ends our for loop.

This is consistent with the process described at the beginning.